# How much data we can send to a restapi?

Tags: json, api, rest, asp.net-web-api

Is there any limit on sending JSON data to a rest API?I am building an app where I have used a rest API to send an email. Here I want to send app logs to API,but before going through that I want to know about the limitation on send data to rest API.

Secondly which one is better option file or send JSON data to rest API?

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET there's by default a 4MB limit of the size of a request. This can be adjusted using the `maxRequestLength` attribute on the [`httpRuntime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641(v=vs.85).aspx) element:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" maxRequestLength="1048576" />
```

In this example we set the maximum request size to be 1GB.

> Secondly which one is better option file or send JSON data to rest API?

If you are planning to send large request payloads I would recommend you using the [`multipart/form-data`](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt) content type for the request instead of JSON. This would allow you to directly send the raw bytes in the request payload. If you use JSON then you would need to encode those raw bytes to something like base64 which would make the request even larger. To even further optimize network traffic the client could gzip the raw bytes before sending them over the wire and then unzip the stream on the server.

You may also find the [following article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-2) useful in setting up this file upload on the server side.